# How to allow clipboard permissions inside apex iframes with includeScript

Tags: visualforce

https://web.dev/async-clipboard/#permissions-policy-integration

I have a visualforce page with this script:

`<apex:includeScript loadOnReady="true" value="{!$Resource.someJS}" />`

this creates an iframe, but I need to pass the "allow" attribute to it. Any ideas on how I can do that natively?

I'm trying to use the Clipboard API in the someJS file but it's giving me permissions issues

Comment: I have created an idea for this, it should be implemented by salesforce unfortunately: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000PzzWRUAZ/permission-policies-for-vf-pages-to-allow-use-of-clipboard-api